# CakePHP 2.1 new install Missing Controller Error

Tags: cakephp, installation

I am completely new to CakePHP and installed 2.1. I am getting this error:

> Missing Controller
>
> Error: Index.phpController could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class Index.phpController below in file: app\Controller\Index.phpController.php
>
> <?php
> class Index.phpController extends AppController {
>
> }
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_controller.ctp
>
> Stack Trace
>
> APP\webroot\index.php line 96 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
> ROOT\index.php line 40 → require(string)

I followed their guide at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html and tried everything it stated:

- I enabled mod_rewrites (they were already enabled from something else)
- I have all the .htaccess files in the directories
- I have cake installed under my document root so I access it at localhost/cakephp/index.php

I do not know where to proceed from here. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 4):

*Update:* I just re-read your question and realized you're loading http://localhost/cakephp/index.php.  Don't do that.  Since you appended "index.php", it is trying to load a controller called "index.php" and the action "index" for that controller.  Resulting mapped path to the "index.php controller" is app\Controller\Index.phpController.php.

Since you have the rewrites enabled, browse to http://localhost/cakephp without appending any filename.

---

*Original answer:*

Assuming you're using Apache, double-check the .htaccess in your /app/webroot directory.  It should include the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Based on your error, it doesn't look like it's properly appending the path after your index.php file.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what is there.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @amg55nj Answer has been corrected.  It's not a rewrite error, it's because you're not respecting the CakePHP rewrite structure.

Comment: Thanks for replying. When I go to http://localhost/cakephp it gives me a list of the files in that directory. I'm not sure why when as you stated I have rewrites enabled.

Comment: @amg55nj go to http://localhost/cakephp/pages/home to view the default home page with Cake's debugging checks.  It may have more guidance for you.

Comment: I get "Not Found" at that url so looked in my directory structure and navigated to localhost/cakephp/app/view/pages/home and still get nothing. I have no idea why nothing is working.

Comment: @amg55nj You cannot navigate to that URL as you have specified.  /pages/home actually exists as "ROOT\lib\Cake\View\Pages\home.ctp" and will only be loaded by the controller "ROOT\lib\Cake\Controller\PagesController.php".  You can override it by creating your own view "ROOT\app\View\Pages\home.ctp".  I think you don't fully understand Cake's url rewriting and have misconfigured it.  I regret I can't be more help, but there is little I can do.

Comment: I thank you for helping me as much as you have. If anything you have guided me on the right path. I def do not understand cake fully or even at all as I'm just learning but I do not know what I could have misconfigured as I did not change anything from the installation instructions. Also, I may be completely wrong here but I do not see a pages folder under root\lib\cake\view\. I only see elements, errors, helper, scaffolds

Comment: @amg55nj My apologies, I didn't pay attention to Pages being moved for v2.1.  The structure I listed was for v2.0.  As of 2.1, the home checks are in \app\View\Pages\home.ctp.  Regardless, the URL "localhost/cakephp/app/view/pages/home" would attempt to load the View action of AppController.php, which is not valid.

Comment: One other quick question....do you know why my folders do not automatically go to the index page like they would on a website? Even when I navigate to localhost/phpmyadmin I have to select the index.php page to log in.

Comment: @amg55nj add "DirectoryIndex index.php" to your .htaccess file in the root directory. [More info about DirectoryIndex setting.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html)

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @amg55nj I'm glad you found this helpful, even if it did not directly answer your question.  You are free to upvote the answer (and mark's as well if his was helpful).  I don't mean this to be pushy in any way, but simply mentioning since you are a new user.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: I cannot upvote as it states that I have to have 15 reputation first. Sorry...I will once I get the reputation amount.

Comment: @amg55nj No problem, just a friendly indoctrination to SO.  Good luck with your website!

Comment: Wanted to let you know that you were right and after changing the DirectoryIndex in my httpd file, it is now working. I added index.php so it now looks like:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Shouldn't this have already been that way when I installed PHP?

Comment: @amg55nj DirectoryIndex is an Apache setting, not PHP.  I'm not sure the default setting.

Comment: Yes I see that I changed it under Apache's setting but I wonder if the default is just index.html or if the index.php should have been there from the start. Oh well, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cakephp 2.0 or greater than rename the controller file name as the class name.
ie `TaskController.php`

```
class TasksController extends AppController {

--Your code inside class
}
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution is to stick to the "live environment" as close as possible.
this means using vhosts to use a "domain" and correctly root down to your webroot dir:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/

this leaves almost no room for error and also helps with other potential problems like "absolutely linked asset files" etc

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, but he'll still get an error when he browses to a vhost and attempts to view "index.php".  :)

Comment: why would you want to browse manually to index.php? what is the actual url you are using?

Comment: It's in the stack trace.  I missed it the first time too.  He enabled rewrites, and then tried to navigate to index.php

Comment: mod_rewrite cannot or shoudn't be enabled dynamically. it is either on or off (hopefully the first). but you still didnt post the actual url you are putting in the browser.

Comment: i guess you didnt really read my tutorial. otherwise you would have spotted, that you don't put anything after the last slash: `http://domain/` (especially no index.php stuff)

Comment: I am not the question asker, so I can't post the actual URL that the _asker_ put in the browser.  Nor would I read your tutorial when you make no indication that the URL is a link to an external resource as opposed to an example of the technique you recommended.

Comment: tried with no luck. still getting same error. 
my root\index.php file at line 40 is this:

require APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'index.php';

is that correct?

Comment: @mark when I go to just the url without typing in index.php, I get a listing of the files in the directory

Comment: did you restart apache after changing mod_rewrite? is there any strange htaccess stuff in your htaccess file? what are the files it lists? maybe you linked to the wrong path?

Comment: Thanks for your replies....yes I restarted apache. no strange stuff in htaccess files. I did not change anything and they are in all 3 folders including root, app, app/webroot. The files listed are the ones in the root directory of cake:
Parent Directory
README
app/
build.properties
build.xml
index.php
lib/
plugins/
vendors/

Comment: ah^^ now i see that there are two commenters here on it. sry for that! @amg55nj: there you got your answer. you are wrongly linking the vhost - as clearly outlined in the post you absolutely need to link it down to /app/webroot/ (!)

Comment: @farray: and yes, you are right - if he keeps on trying to open some "index.php" he will face this problem the next couple of years.

Comment: @mark Thanks for your help. I had to add index.php to my DirectoryIndex in my httpd file.

Comment: thats a very uncommon thing.. never heard of that before. but glad it worked out all right!

Comment: Yeah I thought it was strange as well and not something I would ever think of. I wonder if I was suppose to add index.php before or if it should have already been there. At least its working now....thanks for all your help!